# Get element attribute value inside JQuery each

Tags: jquery

I am getting all form elements which have the name attribute and I need to get the name. So I have;

```
$form.find("input[name], textarea[name]").each(function (index, value) {
  console.log(value.attr("name"));
})
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: value.attr is not a function

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
$form.find("input, textarea").each(function (index, value) {
  console.log($(value).attr("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert element i.e. `value` to jQuery object.

```
$form.find("input[name], textarea[name]").each(function (index, value) {
  console.log($(value).attr("name"));
})
```